# Can i add an alternate url in jsoup if the first one fails?

Tags: android, url, jsoup

I am using Jsoup in my Android application. Is there any method to try another URL if the first URL is broken?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();
```

Here the url directs to a file which is stored in my Dropbox folder. I want the program to check alternate url if the first one fails. Is there any method for that?

Comment: Please post your code regarding what you have done and update your question with more detail what you wish to achieve

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I have editted my question. Please look at it.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails" ? That it gives a 404 ? That there is a network error ? ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup did not provide this function.
Maybe you can try this to solve the problem:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();
if(null == doc){
    doc = Jsoup.connect(anotherUrl).timeout(5000).get();
}
```

Comment: This won' work for responses like 404 not found - you still get a response, and your document will not be null - it will contain the error page the server sent.

Comment: @JonasCz When I try this,I found connect to 404 page will throw exception,you can catch the exception and reset url to fetch page.http://i.stack.imgur.com/0tSwG.jpg